# anybody has an idea about converting curl request to json

Tags: json, curl

sample request : curl -H "Snapdeal-Affiliate-Id:aaaaa" -H "Snapdeal-Token-Id:bbbbb" "affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:586:1461823?expiresAt=1441751400001&signature=cvtwgjgrrbozmumlaalg" -H "Accept:application/xml"

Comment: Please clarify: You want to send a request using curl which takes a json object instead of a multipart form, or you expect to receive a json response after sending a request using curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by importing this curl format in postman client. It then gives us the sample request ,its headers and body. which makes it quite easire for us to respond to curl request.[image]

[image]